# Как исправить ошибку ImportError: cannot import name 'InlineKeyboardMarkup' from 'telebot'?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Сделал загрузку модулей telebot и pyTelegramBotAPI, но вылазит ошибка : "ImportError: cannot import name 'InlineKeyboardMarkup' from 'telebot'", с чем может быть связанно?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import config
from telebot import InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telebot import InlineKeyboardButton



bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

CALLBACK_BUTTON1_MTF = "callback_button1_mtf"

TITLES = {
    CALLBACK_BUTTON1_MTF:"МТФ"
}
def get_base_inline_keyboard():
    keyboard =[
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(TITLES[CALLBACK_BUTTON1_MTF], callback_data = CALLBACK_BUTTON1_MTF)
        ]
    ]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,False)
    user_markup.row('Розклад дзвінків','Розклад занять')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Доброго дня,я Бот - ЦНТУ,в мені є розклад дзвінків,та розклад занять кожної групи...', reply_markup= user_markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == "Розклад дзвінків":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"1. 8:30-9:50"
                                         "\n2. 10:00-11:20"
                                         "\n3. 11:50 - 13:10"
                                         "\n4. 13:20 - 14:40"
                                         "\n5. 14:50 - 16:10"
                                         "\n6. 16:20 - 17:40"
                                         "\n7. 17:50 - 19:10")
    if message.text == "Розклад занять":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Виберіть ваш факультет',reply_markup=get_base_inline_keyboard())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Приложите код с ошибкой

Comment: @Dareten сделано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Всё верно потому что*     **InlineKeyboardMarkup** *находится в* **types**

```
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup
```

*А вы в 4 строчке делаете импорт так:*

```
from telebot import InlineKeyboardMarkup
```